# How to count the keypress realtime in android

Tags: java, android, keypress

How can you count the number of keypress realtime?? or by keypress?
Here is my code:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnKeyListener {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    EditText ed

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ed=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
       ed.setOnKeyListener(this);
       }

   @Override
    public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {

            keyCounter++;
      Log.d("key","" + keyEvent.getKeyCode());

     return super.onKeyUp(i, keyEvent) ;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_B:

                keyCounter++;
                return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

I tried both the onkeyup and on key.. But it didnt work;
I Toast the value of keyCounter but still zero. Anyone knows how to get the number of keypress in android?? Thanks.

Comment: Toast is an horrible way to debug.. have you sonsidered Log.d("tag","Soemthing")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying with a real keyboard or the software keyboard?

> android.view.View.OnKeyListener
>
> Class Overview
>
> Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when a **hardware** key event is dispatched to this view.

see if you can use a TextChangedListener instead.

```
myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            //do stuff
        }

    });
```

Other things:

1) use Log.d instead of Toast.

2) Try the keyCounter++; without conditions to see if the onKey is called.

3) change return false/true to return super.onKey(keyCode, event)

Comment: remove the if part to check if onKey is called.

Comment: Still the same. I changed the return value to what you said. No luck.

Comment: I hope you are using a hardware keyboard and not the software one ;-)

Comment: The emulator? Ahm no Im using my device. :)

Comment: WOW.It works. Ahm your code works on the emulator. the addtextchange(). But why it isnt working on a real device?

Comment: Never mind my previous comment.. My fault I didnt check the android device in logcat.. THANKS.. Ill accept your answer..